# ASP.NET Core container runs on custom port 8080 but ASP.NET container runs on fixed port 80 in Docker Windows

Tags: asp.net, windows, docker, asp.net-core

I made two containers based on following images:

ASP.NET Core
`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019`

ASP.NET
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016`

I run both containers as follows:

`docker run -d -p 8080:8080 aspcore`
`docker run -d -p 9090:9090 asp`

ASP.NET Core container runs on port 8080 and I can open it in browser `http://localhost:8080` but ASP.NET container doesn't work on `http://localhost:9090`

`docker ps -a` shows that ASP.NET core is running on `0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp` while ASP.NET is running on `80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9090->9090/tcp`

Which means ASP.NET is only accessible via some IP on port 80 for e.g. `http://172.20.235.45/`. This IP is of Hyper-V virtual adapter.

Even if I build that image with `EXPOSE 9090`, its behavior is still the same.

In short, ASP.NET Core container works both ways:
`http://localhost:8080`
`http://172.20.235.46:8080`

But ASP.NET container is only accessible as:
`http://172.20.235.45/`

Why is it behaving like this? Is it because of how its base image is built by Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) docs:

> The `EXPOSE` instruction doesn't actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.

So specifying `EXPOSE 9090` will not change the port the ASP.NET is listening.

You are free to map "internal" port to any external one so the easiest option would be to just map ([publish](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish)) the default `80` of the container to the `9090`:

```
docker run -d -p 9090:80 asp
```

If you want to change the "internal" port you will need to handle the IIS config which is used as web server in the container.

Also note that `8080` is the default port for ASP.NET Core images since 8th version.